# Can someone explain me what this math's method does?

Tags: java, math, rounding

i have seen this following math method called:

```
Math.round(d*10000) / (double) 10000;
```

and i don't know what it means. can someone please explain me ?
thank you

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-math-round-method-example/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/479156

Comment: It's trying to round a number to four decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `d` is a `double` or `float`. It multiplies `d` with `10000`. Rounds to the nearest whole number, and divides by `10000`

If effect, it returns the original number with '4 digits as decimal fraction' (without resorting to formatting to String and parsing)

Comment: Sort of. Since a java double is an IEEE binary floating point type it cannot represent this result exactly. The notion of decimal "digits" can really only be effectively supported by a decimal type, which is `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: Correct. Although it cannot be exactly represented, it won't matter too much, unless the number is so large the least significant digits won't fit the mantissa.